# How should I implement concurrency in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I have a program where based on user input a number of instances of Thread child Example classes are created and started. Besides that, Example class also starts a number of threads, based on user input. The whole point of the code is to send requests.

As of right now, user could run into computer resource limitation due to a big number of threads created. What are the possible solutions to avoid that? Should I use threads + queues, multiprocessing, asyncio or anything else?

Thanks in advance

```
import threading
import time
import requests


class Example(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, number_of_request):
        super().__init__()
        self.number_of_requests = number_of_request
        

    def run(self):
        for i in range(0, self.number_of_requests):
            threading.Thread(target=self.function()).start()


    def function(self):
        requests.post("some url")
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_of_entries = int(input("Enter number of entries:"))
    number_of_requests = int(input("Enter number of requests"))
    for i in range(0, number_of_entries):
        Example(number_of_requests).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this problem

1 - asyncio + aiohttp

2 - threading

3 - multiprocessing

4 - asyncio + aiosonic

It all just depends on how much resources your computer and network has

Hope this hels :)